# How to read encoder ticks from arduino with pyserial

Tags: ros, arduino, differential-drive, encoders

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using a arduino due to read two encoders for wheel position. How do I send those number strings to the pyserial and have pyserial read it as left, right wheel(for ros Odom)? I am not all that good at programming, so how would I setup up the sending side and the receiving side? The encoders resolution is 4096 tick/rev and full motor speed is 3k rpm. I am using the output for the differential_drive ros package.
http://www.ros.org/wiki/differential_drive

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60175/how-to-read-encoder-ticks-from-arduino-with-pyserial/) by [packrat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3685/packrat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2013-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Packrat,

Not quite what you're after, but you might find this useful:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/ros_arduino_bridge
It's an arduino bridge to ROS that handles odometry & encoders onboard, and is a lot more lightweight than pyserial.

There's a lot of functionality from the differential drive in there too, like PID feedback for speeds.

Cheers,
Gavin

---

Originally posted by [Gav](https://answers.ros.org/users/3961/gav/) with karma: 478 on 2013-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [packrat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3685/packrat/) on 2013-04-09**:
Well all processing is done by the onboard pc. I am trying to use the arduino as a relay to send the encoder ticks to the PC.